# Cubic monic polynomial over z_p

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, finite-fields

Let
$$
f_{a}(x)=x^3+(u-2-a)x^2+ax+1,
$$
where $u\in\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is fixed. Let $S$ be the set consisting of all $a\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $f_{a}(x)$ factor linearly. Then what is the cardinality of $S$?
Can we  get an exact formula?

Comment: I'm reminded of what Shanks called the simplest cubics, $x^3=ax^2+(a+3)x+1$.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447972/cubic-polynomial-over-mathbbz-p from same OP.

Comment: Probably not - this is a genus 1 curve.